# Where is namespace std defined?

Tags: c++, std

I want to take a peek inside of namespace std but, i'm not able to actually find the file on my computer where it is defined. I tried googling this but, i haven't had much luck.

Comment: There are *many* standard library header files, each one of these defined names inside the `std` namespace. These isn't a single file you can check.

Comment: I thought in order to define a namespace you had to do something like `namespace name { ... } `. That's not something i will find ?

Comment: That is how you define namespaces, but it is done over many files.

Comment: So how would i know everything that is being included when i do `using namespace std`?

Comment: There is no way to know. It depends on which headers you have included and what these headers have included themselves. You should not say `using namespace std;`. It invariably leads to trouble.

Comment: Sounds pretty dumb to me. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You'll know when something doesn't compile unless you specify the std namespace. But juanchopanza is right. Don't do using namespace in general.

Comment: It is certainly dumb to say `using namespace std;`.

Comment: How is it dumb rage? A namespace wraps a scope. It's a name that is prepended to all inside the scope to avoid ambiguity

Comment: I think it's dumb that you can't know what is being included when you do `using namespace std`. Not that i'm dying to use that anyway i was just curious to see if i could see what was inside of that namespace.

Comment: A good approach is to know what you need to use, then if you don't know which header it is in, look it up in a reference (for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/), and include the required header.

Comment: "I think it's dumb that you can't know what is being included when you do `using namespace std`. " That is one of the reasons it is a bad idea to do that!

Answer (score 4):

On most Unix systems, the C++ headers are usually stored in `/usr/include/c++/<version>/`, where `<version>` is the GCC/libstdc++ version (i.e. `4.9` or `4.9.2`), or else the libc++ version i.e. `v1`.

Within that directory are all (or just most?) of the standard-mandated headers, which are mostly just ordinary C++ code. For libstdc++, note in particular that most of the older headers just include something in `bits/`; few of the C++11-specific headers do this.

Answer (score 3):

A list of every thing included in `namespace std` can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library#Standard_headers).

If you are using Visual Studio you can find it locally here :
`~\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC\crt\src`

There is also an online representation [here.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/files.html)

**NOTE** : Edit the src files at your own risk, I'd recommend not editing them at all.

Comment: *If* they did indeed install it.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the things implemented in the `std` namespace are templated, which means their entire implementation will be in the header files. For example, `std::vector` should be in the `vector` header file. Simply look at the options for your compiler to find out where those header files are located.

There may be some non-templated parent classes and free standing functions, which will not be in the headers. Again, look at the compiler documentation to see if the source files are included somewhere and where they would be.